# Getting window geometry in Go for Windows

Tags: winapi, go

I want to create a tool with Go that lets me resize multiple windows on my screen. As an example lets assume that I want to find my Firefox window and my Atom (text editor) window and place them, so that they take up exactly half of my screen (FF left, Atom right).

So far I realized, that I need to use the Windows API for that. I created a method that gives me all handles and the titles of all windows, but I'm struggling with geometry information. I understand that the api call `GetWindowRect` will help, but how can I get the information out of a pointer to a rect?

Follow up question 1: what other information can I get about the windows?
Follow up question 2: How do I resize the window so that it takes exactly half my screen size? I guess, I need another call to get the monitor dimensions.

What I have so far is the code below. The main program finds all handles and displays those containing 'Atom' in the title. The windows package contains the code accessing the windows API.

My current result is that I get 2 handles for atom (why not just 1?). I guess, I have to learn more about the Windows API, too. Are there good summaries to understand the basics?

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "resizer/windows"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const title = "Atom"    
    m := windows.GetAllWindows()
    fmt.Printf("Map of windows: \n")
    for handle := range m {
        if strings.Contains(m[handle].Title(), title) {
            fmt.Printf("'%v'\n", m[handle])
        }
    }
}
```

**windows.go:**

```
package windows

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    user32             = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    procEnumWindows    = user32.MustFindProc("EnumWindows")
    procGetWindowTextW = user32.MustFindProc("GetWindowTextW")
)

// Window represents any Window that is opened in the Windows OS
type Window struct {
    handle syscall.Handle
    title  string
}

// Title returns the title of the window
func (w Window) Title() string {
    return w.title
}

// GetAllWindows finds all currently opened windows
func GetAllWindows() map[syscall.Handle]Window {
    m := make(map[syscall.Handle]Window)
    cb := syscall.NewCallback(func(h syscall.Handle, p uintptr) uintptr {
        bytes := make([]uint16, 200)
        _, err := GetWindowText(h, &bytes[0], int32(len(bytes)))
        title := "||| no title found |||"
        if err == nil {
            title = syscall.UTF16ToString(bytes)
        }
        m[h] = Window{h, title}
        return 1 // continue enumeration
    })
    EnumWindows(cb, 0)
    return m
}

// EnumWindows loops through all windows and calls a callback function on each
func EnumWindows(enumFunc uintptr, lparam uintptr) (err error) {
    r1, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procEnumWindows.Addr(), 2, uintptr(enumFunc), uintptr(lparam), 0)
    if r1 == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = syscall.EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}

// GetWindowText gets the title of a Window given by a certain handle
func GetWindowText(hwnd syscall.Handle, str *uint16, maxCount int32) (len int32, err error) {
    r0, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procGetWindowTextW.Addr(), 3, uintptr(hwnd), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(str)), uintptr(maxCount))
    len = int32(r0)
    if len == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = syscall.EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: You've better to use Window Class Name instead of Caption. Because you my open text editor with filename `Firefox.txt`. And you should implement API wrapper of MoveWIndow to move the windows. And  GetSystemMetrics to get screen size.

Comment: the classname is definitely helpful. However, I still have two Atom handles (and only one window). Any idea how to get the screen sizes of the two?

Comment: The follow-up questions are extremely vague. There's a lot you can do with a window and a lot you can get out of it. You're better off sticking to what you want to know. Also note: when calling functions like `GetWindowTextW()`, you have to check MSDN to make sure the length you're passing is properly accounting for the terminating NUL character (integer value 0) that comes at the end of C strings but that `syscall.UTF16ToString()` strips. There are ways to get the precise length you need as well.

Comment: And yes, this kind of thing will require understanding Windows closely. You should read somethng like Programming Windows: 5th Edition.

Comment: You can get screen size with like this: https://github.com/mattn/gopher/blob/ca807c5d98431662634aa7e060dce4c031b1eb2d/cmd/gopher/bitmap.go#L127-L129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetWindowRect()` writes the geometry to the `RECT` structure you pass the pointer to in. It operates exactly like the `GetWindowText()` call you already have; the difference is you have to provide the `RECT` structure yourself.

You *should* be able to just get away with copying the structure verbatim. To substitute data types, use [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). The definition for [`RECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx) says all the fields are `LONG`, which that page says is "[a] 32-bit signed integer". So this *should* suffice:

```
type RECT struct {
    left   int32 // or Left, Top, etc. if this type is to be exported
    top    int32
    right  int32
    bottom int32
}
```

(Most likely irrelevant, but it's worth pointing out that `RECT` operates identically to `image.Rectangle`, with `left` and `top` being `Min` and `right` and `bottom` being `Max`. They are not identical because `image.Rectangle` uses `int`, so you may want to consider providing conversion functions if you want to use `image`'s geometry functions to manipulate rectangles instead of GDI's.)

Comment: good solution although by now I found https://github.com/AllenDang/w32 which makes my life a lot easier in general